# How to correct these syntax errors in a SQL script generated by PowerDesigner in SQL Server?

Tags: database, syntax-error, sql-server-2014, sql-scripts, powerdesigner

> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'
>
> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'
>
> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'delete'
>
> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'varchar'
>
> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'restrict'

I can't seem to generate a complete and correct Database with this only 5 of the tables are generated.

Comment: Add your SQL Statement as Text not as image

Comment: Looks like it is written for SQL-Server not for mysql

Comment: Yes Sorry . it is !

Comment: Can you put the script back? It looks like it was dropped with Edit 4.

Comment: From PowerDesigner, it looks like your model is using some version of SQL Anywhere / Adaptive Server Anywhere DBMS. What is your actual target DBMS? brand/name/version...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your generated syntax seems to be for SQL Server.

The correct MySQL syntax for dropping a foreignkey is:

```
alter table ARTICLE drop foreign key FK_ARTICLE_CONTENIR_ACHAT
```

And take note that the **foreign key** constraint has to be dropped by **constraint name**.

Comment: How do I drop a Foreign Key without knowing the name of the constraint?

Comment: @SonaLegends: you cannot - you must know the name of the FK constraint.